# What is "lucid enough in our minds to be ambiguous"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> None of us are clear as yet upon some of the most vital questions
> before us, we are not **lucid** enough in out own minds to be **ambiguous**,
> and a mumbling tactfulness and indirect half-statements made with an
> eye upon some censor, will confuse our thoughts and the thoughts of
> those with whom we desire understanding, **to the complete sterilization**
> and defeat of every reconstructive effort
>
> *bolds are mine

*- The new world order by H.G. Wells*

I want to know the word 'ambiguous' belongs to what? To "lucid enough to be ambiguous"? Is this reasonable in a sentence?

My other question is, where does "to the complete sterilization" part belong to? Does it mean "tactfulness will confuse us until the world is sterilized from every reconstructive effort?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this is a monstrously confusing sentence, and I had to think hard about it myself.  At first, I thought "ambiguous" might be a mistake and he meant "lucid enough to be **unambiguous**".  But after reading the rest of the sentence carefully, he could also mean "we are not yet lucid enough to deal with ambiguous/complicated statements without getting confused".

The whole thing seems to boil down to something like: "None of us are clear on these questions yet, and if we have to politely refrain from discussing it or saying anything clear about it unless we are absolutely sure, we will never get anything discussed and we will never get anything done".

Regarding your second point, I think you're correct.  This use of "to", describing the outcome of something, is an idiom, meaning something like "leading to".

Comment: Well, I got the same idea as you at the first sight. I didn't think it was so confusing. As you said it means it is obvious to us that is so complicated to proceed with anything furthur.